# Subscribe works in constructor but html returns undefined - Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, subscribe

I'm having trouble downloading data in the API and viewing it on the page. The data subscribes in constructor and then wants to pass @Input to child components. After some time after reloading the page, the data appears correctly in the view, but unfortunately, the console displays errors :(
What am I doing wrong?

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name opinions' of undefined

```
constructor(
    private ActivatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private cityService: CityRegionDataService
  ) {
    this.ActivatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.city = params.get('city');
      this.region = params.get('region');
    });

    this.cityService.getCityData(this.city).subscribe(resp => {
      this.cityData = resp.body;
    });

in html

<app-opinions [city]="cityData.nameOpinions"></app-opinions>
```

Comment: Looks like either you are not using the correct name or you are not passing the value correctly or you are not adding any conditional operator to ensure the data is loaded first like the elvis operator ?.. Which is your problem(s) is difficult to tell because the code is not complete. Please include an [mcve].

Comment: Also you should put any application logic including getting route values in `ngOnInit` using the `OnInit` interface. Do not add this in the constructor. All the basic tutorials in the [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial) on the angular.io site explain this. This is also an excellent site to use to follow a tutorial to get started.

Comment: Names of variables are corretctly, because after a while everythings works fine and correctly appears on site. The problem was not to add the elvis operator.

Comment: <app-opinions [city]="cityData?.nameOpinions"></app-opinions> WORKS thanks!

Comment: Key is to understand why `https://read.hyperight.com/is-data-mesh-right-for-your-organisation/` works. The reason is that the first time the HTML is rendered (i.e. at the Component construction time) the variable `this.cityData` is null since the invocation of `getCityData` has not yet returned anything. When later `getCityData` returns something, the `subscribe` method makes sure that the function passed to it as parameter gets executed. Such function sets `this.cityData` value to the data returned. An update of a variable of the component fires the re-render and therefore the data is seen.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding.?  In the variable like this:

<app-opinions [city]="cityData?.nameOpinions">

Answer (score 0):

Your template is trying to access `cityData.nameOpinions` before the service call has set the value of cityData. As Nikolas mentioned in their answer you can use the safe navigation operator `cityData?.nameOpinions` will return undefined instead of an error when `cityData` is undefined.

```
<app-opinions [city]="cityData?.nameOpinions"></app-opinions>
```